# Error installing .apk from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

I'm downloading from a FTP server an .apk file to update my application. My relevant code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);
if (file.exists()) {
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

When the intent is launched (in the last line, `context.startActivity(intent);`) it just say that there has been an error analyzing the package (or something like that, I'm not sure how the message is in english). The .apk has been signed.

I have not a single clue about what's wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer process cannot access files on internal storage of your app. And, since last I checked, you cannot install from a `ContentProvider`, you will have to move the file to some location on external storage.

Comment: What about if file is written with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` permission in Internal Storage?

Comment: @user370305: Those were deprecated a couple of years ago, and I would not count on them working.

Comment: Ohh.. OK. that's the matter. :)